# Problem calculating a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the integral from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ of the following function: $z\operatorname{Im}(z) + \operatorname{Re}(z) + 2z\overline z$ on the parabola $y=x^2$.

The problem is that when I switch to $y$, I end up with the integral $d(x+ix^2)$...and I don't know what to do with the $x^2$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want the integral over *the whole parabola* $\;y=x^2\;$ ?? Because if you do then you'll get an improper  integral...

Comment: No, from (0,0) to (1,1)

Comment: Then why don't you write down that explicitly in your question?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Put $\;z=x+iy\sim(x,y)\;$ , and then your function is

$$f(z)=(x+iy)y+x+2x^2+2y^2\;\;(\text{ since}\;\;z\overline z=|z|^2=x^2+y^2\;$ )$$

The parametrization of that chunk of that parabola is $\;(t, t^2)\,,\,\,\;$  so

$$\int_{y=x^2}f(z)\,dz=\int_\alpha^\beta(t^3+2t^2+2t^4, t^4)\cdot(1, 2t)dt$$

and you get a rather nice *improper* integral if $\;\alpha,\,\beta\;$ or both are infinite...

Comment: Thank you!  
What happened to the i's?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been a little clearer: it is clear that I am using the dientification $\;\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2\;$ , so that we get a usual line integral. That's all. There are no $\;i'$ s in this identification

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when I switch to $y$, I end up with the integral $d(x+ix^2)$...and I don't know what to do with the $x^2$.

Hint: $d( x+ix^2) =dx+d(ix^2)=(1+i\,2x)\, dx$